# Possible causes of javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException

Tags: java, jboss

What are the possible causes of a TransactionRequiredException?

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: JBAS011469:
Transaction is required to perform this operation
(either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
```

We have a setup where we run tests from a normal JVM towards an application container (jboss 7) over the JNDI interface. We have a nightly build that runs this code every night and it usually succeeds. Sometimes however, after a certain time of execution, all tests starts to fail with the above exception without any code change. Can any external issues cause this. We have disk space, and since the exceptions are passed over the network I think the network is also good. Can any of the following cause an exception like this:

- Lack of file descriptors
- Hibernate having problems talking to the database (mysql)
- CPU load
- Out of memory

Sorry if the question got a bit abstract, but I cannot get my head around this one. All solutions and debugging suggestions are more then welcome.

Comment: Transactions don't just randomly disappear. I will suspect it is the connection to the database that is somehow responsible, although I then would expect a different kind of error (connection failures, to be more exact). The fact that you DON'T get an exception here confuses me a great deal.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the tests. Do you have a lot of client transactions from your client to the Server? Does the server insert/modify records in the database? SFSB, SLSB? Currently I'd also bet my money on the database connection, as it's a "random" (aka "after some time problem problem"), I'd focus on the entity manager, perhaps try to flush & reset after every request, to see if you are able to provoke the problem earlier.

Comment: All sessions beans are stateless. Yes we do a lot of transactions. We have about 500 tests and most of them are runs many transactions. I will look more into the database, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: One of your EJB method could have the transaction attribute MANDATORY. And if any your code calls this method without an active transaction it would result in this error TransactionRequiredException. It seems on some occasions you have a active transaction and not in some peculiar cases. Need to look for this particular method which has MANDATORY attribute and debug to understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in the server.log jboss provides. The log shows that at the time when the tests starts to fail, this class:

```
org.hornetq.core.client
```

throws

```
Throwable: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

So an OutOfMemoryError can cause

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: JBAS011469:
Transaction is required to perform this operation
(either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
```